# Extjs Store all fields average

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, store

I have a store like below

```
Ext.define('Result', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'state', type: 'string', mapping:0 },
        { name: 'product', type: 'string', mapping:1 },
        { name: 'quantity', type: 'int', mapping:2 }
        { name: 'price', type: 'int', mapping:3 }
    ]
});
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'Result',
    groupField: 'state',
    data: [
        ['MO','Product 1',50,40],
        ['MO','Product 2',75,50],
        ['MO','Product 3',25,60],
        ['MO','Product 4',125,70],
        ['CA','Product 1',50,50],
        ['CA','Product 2',100,40],
        ['WY','Product 1',250,40],
        ['WY','Product 2',25,50],
        ['WY','Product 3',125,86],
        ['WY','Product 4',175,83]
    ]
});
```

I want to calculate the average of quantity and price of every state group and show it into the grid .
I have seen in the sencha documentation, there is a function like [average](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-average)(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-average)
and I can Implement it like

```
store.avarage('quantity', true);
```

but it only gives the average of  only one field .

How and I calculate the average of multiple fields depending on the group and show it in a grid.

Comment: store.avarage('quantity', true);

Comment: So you mean you want the average of fields grouped by state == 'MO', state == 'WY', etcetera?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty yes I want the average like
state ='MO' ,     Quantity=avg of Quantity(state 'MO')                                     Price=  avg of Price(state'MO' )

Comment: @Ivan I Know this function store.avarage('quantity', true); but I want average of more then one fields...

Comment: @Yogeshpatel I just created a fiddle and `average` works: http://jsfiddle.net/Jandalf/Wn4UY/

Comment: He wants them *grouped* and averaged: grouped by state.  See my answer -- it does what he wants.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty and my fiddle does this too and with api methods.

Comment: @JanS Thanks for the answer. but if you see my question carefully .I want average of quantity and price both that is more then one field.your answer only gives me the average of quantity .In addition I want to show the average value of quantity and price grouped according to state in the Ext.grid.
Can you please suggest me some method by which I can do that.

Comment: @Yogeshpatel: ok next try: http://jsfiddle.net/Jandalf/Wn4UY/3/  but I think you need a whole new store to place into the grid, you could merge the result of both average results and place the merged data into the store..

Comment: @JanS your answer is exactly what I want . One last question If you don't mind.can I show only average data in rows hiding the original data.  so only average is shown in a grid.

Comment: @JanS Provide your answers in the answers field . so I can Mark it as answer to this question.

Comment: @JanS I have one more question.
I want to assign Different GroupField to Chart and Grid in this example(http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh8418/d9RRa/) I want 'state' as groupfield in Ext.Chart in the jsfiddle example which is OK . But I want 'product' as a group field in My Ext.Grid So that I can see the average According to the 'product' group and Not according to the 'state' group.

Comment: @Yogeshpatel see my answer, now everything is in one line:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give you a grid with average data only: http://jsfiddle.net/Jandalf/Wn4UY/4/

```
var chartStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: ['state',  'product', 'quantity', 'price'],
    groupField: 'state',
    data: [
        ['MO','Product 1',50,40],
        ['MO','Product 2',75,50],
        ['MO','Product 3',25,60],
        ['MO','Product 4',125,70],
        ['CA','Product 1',50,50],
        ['CA','Product 2',100,40],
        ['WY','Product 1',250,40],
        ['WY','Product 2',25,50],
        ['WY','Product 3',125,86],
        ['WY','Product 4',175,83]
    ]
});

var data = [];
var quantities = chartStore.average("quantity", true);
var prices = chartStore.average("price", true);
Ext.each(chartStore.collect('state'), function(item){
    data.push({
        state: item,
        quantity: quantities[item],
        price: prices[item]
    });
});

var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['state', 'quantity', 'price'],
    groupField: 'state',
    data: data
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    store: gridStore,
    columns: [
        { dataIndex: 'state', text: 'State' },
        { dataIndex: 'quantity', text: 'Quantity' },
        { dataIndex: 'price', text: 'Price' }
    ]
});
```

if you want a chart with a different grouping you need a extra store, you can't define 2 'views' for a store.

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way to address the data issue -- I've appended each record with average quantity and price fields.  I'll leave it to you as an exercise as to how to appropriately update the fields setting above data in your example:

```
data: (function() {
    var data = [
        ['MO','Product 1',50,40],
        ['MO','Product 2',75,50],
        ['MO','Product 3',25,60],
        ['MO','Product 4',125,70],
        ['CA','Product 1',50,50],
        ['CA','Product 2',100,40],
        ['WY','Product 1',250,40],
        ['WY','Product 2',25,50],
        ['WY','Product 3',125,86],
        ['WY','Product 4',175,83]
    ];

    var qtyByState = {};
    var priceByState = {};
    var record;
    var state;

    for (var i=0, n=data.length; i<n; i++) {
        record = data[i];
        state = record[0];

        if (!qtyByState[state]) {
            qtyByState[state] = {
                total: 0,
                nbr: 0,
            }
        }

        if (!priceByState[state]) {
            priceByState[state] = {
                total: 0,
                nbr: 0
            }
        }

        qtyByState[state].avg = (qtyByState[state].total += record[2]) / ++qtyByState[state].nbr;
        priceByState[state].avg = (priceByState[state].total += record[3]) / ++priceByState[state].nbr;
    }

    for (var i=0, n=data.length; i<n; i++) {
        record = data[i];
        state = record[0];
        record.push(qtyByState[state].avg);
        record.push(priceByState[state].avg);
    }

    return data;
})()
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.You solution provides the average in every field that is average in every (all 10) row.But I want average in only three unique 'state' rows only 3 rows ('MO',CA,WY) as a result so that I can show it in the Ext grid.
Thanks once again.